# クラスの中で使う関数の宣言方法

Tags: c++

クラスのメンバ関数を実装するとき、メンバ関数にするまでもないけれど、関数化したほうが使いやすいような手続き（10行くらい）はどう実装していますか？

例）friend関数、プライベートメンバ関数にしてしまう、必要な値を全部引数にとるような関数を作る

Comment: 私の場合、friend関数、privateメンバ関数、値を引数に展開する関数などの形を決めるのは、その関数を、誰にどのようにアクセスさせたいかによると考えています。関数のサイズは、基本的に考慮しません。例えば、クラスの外部には使わせたくない関数なら、privateまたはprotectedなメンバ関数にします。別の例として、そのクラスに関係なく、いろいろなところで使えそうな関数なら、値を引数に展開した関数にします。

Comment: なるほど！アクセスのさせ方という説明はとても分かりやすいです。ありがとうございました！